# How to move a php file to bitbucket and how to run that file?

Tags: php, git, bitbucket

I am fresher in using bitbucket , so that I don't know how to use it.
I want to set a mailgun server in bitbuket with a mail sending function using php.
As a first step  I created a repositroy in the bitbucket and download Git.
How can I set a mailgun server using php and how to test it?How to move the locally created php file to bitbucket?Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitbucket is not a Host, it only gives you a service for hosting a Git or Mercurial Repositiory. If you are looking for a free FTP Server look at [bplaced.net](http://www.bplaced.net) or [something like that](https://www.google.com.pk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=free%20php%20hosting&safe=off).

Some similar question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618888/is-it-possible-to-host-and-run-a-script-on-bitbucket).

Answer (score 2):

You probably have some misconceptions regarding bitbucket and even Git. Give them both a read before you proceed using them.

- [About Bitbucket](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket)
- [What is Git?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software))

You are probably looking for free hosting servers to test your code. Googling it [returned these results](https://www.google.com.pk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=free%20php%20hosting&safe=off). You are free to choose any of these services but I'd recommend you to get a paid host.

In answer to your "how to move a php file to bitbucket" part of question, following is a summarized version on how to "move" (or, as git puts it) `push` a file to a repository.

1. Create a repo on bitbucket.
2. Checkout that repo locally. You can use either use [Git-scm](http://git-scm.com)'s official software or you can use [SourceTree by Altassian](http://www.atlassian.com/SourceTree-Client).
3. Stage your files to be committed.
4. Commit files.
5. Push files to bitbucket.

You can use [Bitbucket's official tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/cgozDQ) outlining detailed steps on how to use it.